# Error adding to mutable list (NPE) Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

---Data Class---

trying to add object to meals MutableList-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
data class YelpRestaurant(

val name: String,
val rating: Double,
val price: String,
@SerializedName("review_count") val numReviews: Int,
@SerializedName("image_url") val imageUrl: String,
val categories: List<YelpCategory>,
val location: YelpLocation,
val meals: MutableList<UserMeals>
```

)

----EDITED ACTIVITY----

```
class ThoughtsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var mealName: String
lateinit var mealPrice: String
lateinit var mealThought: String

lateinit var selected_Restaurant : YelpRestaurant

val meals = mutableListOf<UserMeals>()

@Subscribe(sticky = true)
fun getRest(selectedRestaurant : YelpRestaurant)  {
    selected_Restaurant = selectedRestaurant

}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_thoughts)


    thoughtBtn.setOnClickListener() {

        mealName = m_name.text.toString()
        mealPrice = m_price.text.toString()
        mealThought = m_thought.text.toString()

        var addedMeal = UserMeals(mealName, mealPrice.toDouble(), mealThought)

        if (mealName.isNotEmpty()) {
            selected_Restaurant.meals.add(addedMeal)
        }

    }
}



override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
}
```

}

Comment: `selected_Restaurant` is `null`. Apparently, nothing is calling `getRest()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Attempt to invoke interface method 'void java.util.List.add(int, java.lang.Object)' on a null object. says that the list is null (i think it is `meals` list that is null) thus `selected_Restaurant` could not be null before that

Comment: @Bahman: Oh, yes, you're correct -- I misread the line.

Comment: I am passing the restaurant object into the activity using EventBus so aparently getRest() is not supposed to be called anywhere. The selectedRestaurants other fields can be logged so I dont think the restaurant is null I think the meals list is null and it wont let me add to a null list. Check out the image I attached of the debugger for .add line of code all other fields are passed in just meal = null seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have null pointer exception when accessing `selected_Restaurant.meals` to prevent NPE change `meals` to `val` and instantiate it when you declare it like this in `selected_Restaurant`:

```
val meals = mutableListOf<UserMeals>()
```